# How to get count of records which have duplicate value in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table with player and status, this table not got corrupted and it has duplicate entries like this:

```
player_id      status
----------------------
1           100
2           100
2           101
3           100
1           101
2           101
```

As you can see this record is duplicate: `2,101`

How can I find such records using a mysql query?

I tried:

`select * from player group by player_id, status having count(status) > 1` but it did not help.

Comment: now u got multiple answer, dont forget to chose best answer as mark as accepted..

Answer (score 2):

You can `SELECT` duplicate records as like that:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as total,player_id,`status`
FROM `player` 
GROUP BY player_id,`status` 
HAVING total > 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

Do it in a outer query like

```
select * from (
select *, count(*) as rowcount
from player 
group by player_id, status ) tab
where rowcount > 1
```

Comment: @UndefinedVariable, can't be cause I tried myself and it results in `2 101 2`

Comment: it works, sorry my bad I had a mistake when I ran it. +1!

Comment: yes rahul i have tested your query is also working... good example with sub query...

Answer (score 1):

> You can try this query.

```
$qrys = <<<QUERY
select s.id, t.* 
from player s
join (
    select player_id, status, count(*) as qty
    from player
    group by player_id, status
    having count(*) > 1
) t on s.player_id = t.player_id and s.status = t.status
QUERY;
```

> If you want to delete duplicate record then use this script

```
$delres=  mysql_query($qrys);
$player_id = 0;
$status = 0;
while ($r=  mysql_fetch_array($delres)){
    if($player_id == $r['player_id'] && $status == $r['status'])
    mysql_query("DELETE FROM player WHERE id=".$r['id']);
    $player_id = $r['player_id'];
    $status = $r['status'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this :**

```
select * from player p 
inner join ( select player_id, count(*) as duplicate 
from player group by player_id 
having count(*) > 1) pp 
on p.player_id = pp.player_id
```

Answer (score 0):

You query is near to it just some changes in it to give you count column for every options Try this modified query.

```
select *, count(status) as count from player 
 group by player_id, status having count(status) > 0
```

It will give this type of response

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
SELECT *, COUNT(status) AS rows_count FROM player 
GROUP BY player_id, status HAVING COUNT(status) > 0
```

Answer (score -1):

you can do that by

```
SELECT distinct player .*
  FROM player as tb1
  join player as tb2
 WHERE tb1.status = tb2.status
   and tb1.player_id < tb2.player_id
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do it simply with `GROUP BY` like this

```
SELECT `player_id`, `status`, COUNT(*) as cnt FROM `player` 
GROUP BY CONCAT(`player_id`, '_', `status`) HAVING cnt > 1
```

result would be

```
player_id   status  cnt     
2           101     2
```

Comment: @UndefinedVariable can you retest query ?  i have updated it.